# Noob question - Python, Selenium, XPATH - Search if text is on website

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I've got just an issue with some basic understanding regarding xpath. I've read in the xpath documentation and searched here for some time now (and obviously I have just overseen some basics) but I just got lost with the following case.

```html
<div class="foo">
    <h1 class="title">TRANSFERS</h1>
</div>
```

I know that there are several ways to get the HELLOWORLD from my code using xpath. But what do I do if I just want to search the whole page to see if it contains "HELLOWORLD" anywhere?

Reading the documentation, I came to that statement which gives me an error message:

```html
y = driver.find_element_by_xpath([contains(text()='TRANSFERS')])
```

```html
  File "<ipython-input-587-f5ff19bd101b>", line 1
    y = driver.find_element_by_xpath([contains(text()='TRANSFERS')])
                                               ^
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **xpath** is **wrong**.

Try either of the following `xpath` options to identify text of the node.

```
y = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'TRANSFERS')]")
```

OR

```
y = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(.,'TRANSFERS')]")
```

OR

```
y = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='TRANSFERS']")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but still get an error message:

...

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[text()='TRANSFERS']"}
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)

Comment: Well your initial problem has resolved of syntax error .Have you tried all 3 options i have posted. If so then you need to provide Relevant html or url of the application?

Comment: You are right. The error wasn't caused by the syntax. It was caused by the web application. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this :
Try to create a list with WEBELEMENTS named x and then :

```
    x=driver.find_elements_by_xpath([contains(.,'TRANSFERS')]
```

this won’t cause an error even if it doesn’t find and anything and will just return an empty list
Have fun ;)